# Integrating Yubikey Token details within LDAP with FreeIPA on CentOS

Tags: ldap, centos7, ldap-query, freeipa

I would like to integrate yubikey token details within freeipa's ldap 389 directory server

I'm trying to follow [those instructions](https://www.dalemacartney.com/2012/12/19/integrating-yubikey-token-details-within-ldap-with-freeipa-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6/) to extend ldap schema with yubikey information.  Ldap's extensions don't work out of the box and i'm trying to correct them.
I have changes attributeTypes and objectClasses definition to

`dn: cn=schema
#
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.40789.2012.11.1.2.1 NAME 'yubiKeyId' DESC 'Yubico YubiKey ID' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.21 X-ORIGIN 'Example' )
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.40789.2012.11.1.2.2 NAME 'yubiKeyUser' DESC 'Yubico YubiKey User' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY ( yubiKeyId ) X-ORIGIN 'Example'  )`

With those modifications, ipa is able to restart but when i try to import a token id with the command

`ipa user-mod --addattr="objectClass=yubiKeyUser" --addattr="yubiKeyID=ccccc1234567" user1`

I'm getting the following error ipa: ERROR: yubiKeyId: value #0 invalid per syntax : invalid syntax.

I'm using:
CentOS:  Linux release 7.5.1804 
FreeIPA: VERSION: 4.5.4, API_VERSION: 2.228

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the instructions you've choose to follow and the schema definition is incorrect.
Replace it with this one, and things should work.

`attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.40789.2012.11.1.2.1 NAME 'yubiKeyId' DESC 'Yubico YubiKey ID' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 X-ORIGIN 'Example' )`